# OFFSET command not recognized in Table Adapter Query c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, tableadapter

I am attempting to build the following tableadapter query in Visual Studio 2019

```
SELECT * FROM Vendors
ORDER BY VendorID 
OFFSET 5 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

And it gives the error "Unable to Parse Query Text" at the offset command
I know this query works on the database itself as i can run it successfully on the sql server (2019 Express).

Will Visual Studio tableadapter queries not recognize the offset command?  Or is the syntax different in some way?

Comment: Table adapters are very last century. Have you considered just not using them? :P Alternatively, just put some query in there the designer can easily live with that has the same metadata (please don't use `SELECT *` in production code, it breaks far too easily) and then change the query in the code behind or just yourself at runtime. It seems unlikely you want static values for `OFFSET` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

TableAdapters are pretty old these days, but they do remain a serviceable data access strategy. The designer attempts to parse the query you entered and doesn't like it much with the extra offset parts.

I recommend you try:

- right click your dataset surface
- add >> tableadapter
- "select that downloads rows"
- put the query in as `SELECT * FROM Vendors`
- finish the wizard
- click the `fill,getdata()` line of the adapter
- in the properties grid, paste the extra clause onto the end of the query text
- say "no" to "do you want to update the other queries?"

You should be left with a usable adapter. See the footnote though

You have other options if you want to use a lot of syntax that designer doesn't like; most notably you can say "Create New Stored Procedures" when going through the wizard, put a base query of `SELECT * FROM Vendors`, VS will make the sprocs, and then you can just edit the OFFSET etc into the sproc command in SSMS

Footnote: I personally still use TAs a lot and have never needed such syntaxes, but generally I make the first query in a TA of the form `SELECT * FROM x WHERE ID = @y` so it'll only ever pull one row anyway and is very "plain SQL" - the datatable schema is driven from it and it "just works":

[image]

Then other queries have defined uses such as `SELECT * FROM x WHERE Name LIKE ...`  - If you adopt this approach of making the firt query in a "normal" one that it can cope with, then you can certainly add another query with unsupported syntax - you get an error "unable to parse query text":

[image]

but you can ignore it and finish the wizard anyway, and it will work fine

[image]

Comment: So this worked!  Thanks!  And after it did, , out of curiosity, i went back to the original  tableadapter and created the query and just ignored the warning and saw that the query actually does work, despite the fact that it says unable to parse query.  I just hadn't ever tried it anyway.  How misleading of VS!!  Haha.

Comment: (if you try it from the get go on a new TA you might find it doesn't generate all the queries/doesn't make the datatable properly, hence the reason why I recommend doing it in a way that works the first time.. also, if you change the table in the db, having a broken query will make the changes harder to import)